# Cannot select element on page with any kind of selector with python selenium

Tags: python, selenium

Im trying to simply fill login form, but no matter how much i try I just cannot. I'm trying for two days with all kinds of selectors, nothing. Here is my code:

```
# -*- coding: iso-8859-2 -*-
from __future__ import print_function
import pyautogui, sys
import time
import random
import subprocess
import os
import urllib
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data") #Path to your chrome profile
options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=options)
driver.get("https://awario.com/login?r=%2F")
wait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='loginform-email']"))).click
wait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='loginform-email']"))).send_keys('email')
wait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='loginform-password']"))).send_keys('pass')
```

Comment: You need to be more specific than it doesn't work. What doesn't work? What error messages are you getting, what line is failing, etc.? Be specific and detailed.

Comment: element not found on page..

Comment: Which one? We have no idea from what you've put in your question. Please add some details. List the other locators you've tried along with any error messages you received with each, etc.

Answer (score 0):

recommend you use selenium server way for run and debug script on local as guide: http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html#using-selenium-with-remote-webdriver

The console window running selenium server will print out log of all operation on browser as below:

```
INFO - Executing: [find elements: By.cssSelector: a[ng-if*="uxdRegion"]])
INFO - Done: [find elements: By.cssSelector: a[ng-if*="uxdRegion"]]
INFO - Executing: [get element attribute: 0 [ 
        css selector: a[ng-if*="uxdRegion"]], href])
INFO - Done: [get element attribute: 0 [] -> 
        css selector: a[ng-if*="uxdRegion"]], href]
```

And stop running and print out log when meet exception.
From the log you can easy to know which step in script fail and failed reason.

FYI, the way of using selenium in your above script, called 'directconnect'.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your xpath "//*[@id='loginform-email']" on your login page on my laptop with normal browser size, it will find 3 matched elements.

The first and the second one not visiable, they used for small browser size, like
open your site on mobile device. only the third one visible in my trying.

For selenium not visible element is always not clickable.

In your script you used the api: EC.element_to_be_clickable(), because there are more than one matched element, it will use the first one which is not visible, 
equivalent to not clickable, so EC.element_to_be_clickable() should not return
any element for next click.

you can try with more strict locator as below code on desktop with maixmize browser size to verify my answer correct or not.

css_locator_email = ".top-index-section + div #loginform-email" 
wait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, css_locator_email))).click();